# Mongoose Populate with a condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

in a `Node.js` App with `Mongoose(Mongodb)`, With this code i fetch users and their books:

```
Users.find({user_id: req.user.id}).populate('books').exec(..);
```

Right now i want to fetch users that has an special book. i do like this:

```
Users.find({user_id: req.user.id}).populate('books',null,{bookname:"harry potter"}).exec(..);
```

But it doesn't work. With this, my code fetches users with their books of `null` value and if that condition matches, return them instead of null. In fact most of my users has `null` value for books. but what i want is that if that condioton in populate section is not matches, do not return that user in result array at all!

What i have to do? i have to do another query or something on results for what i need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I can think here is that you are calling it wrong. You do not really show much context here other than that your `.populate()` parameters do not look correct.

Here is a correct listing as a reproducible example:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var thingSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  name: String
},{ _id: false });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  things: [{ type: Number, ref: 'Thing' }]
});

var Thing = mongoose.model( 'Thing', thingSchema ),
    Parent = mongoose.model( 'Parent', parentSchema );

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/thingtest');

var things = { "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3 };

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      async.each([Thing,Parent],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      var parentObj = new Parent({ "name": "me" });
      async.each(
        Object.keys(things).map(function(key) {
          return { "name": key, "_id": things[key] }
        }),
        function(thing,callback) {
          var mything = new Thing(thing);
          parentObj.things.push(thing._id)
          mything.save(callback)
        },
        function(err) {
          if (err) callback(err);
          parentObj.save(callback);
        }
      );
    },
    function(callback) {
      console.log("filtered");
      var options = {
        path: 'things',
        match: { "name": { "$in": ['two','three'] } }
      };

      Parent.find().populate(options).exec(function(err,docs) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        console.log(docs);
        callback();
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      console.log('unfiltered');
      Parent.find().populate('things').exec(function(err,docs) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        console.log(docs);
        callback();
      })
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Which will consistently give results like this:

```
filtered
[ { _id: 55ec4c79f30f550939227dfb,
    name: 'me',
    __v: 0,
    things:
     [ { _id: 2, name: 'two', __v: 0 },
       { _id: 3, name: 'three', __v: 0 } ] } ]
unfiltered
[ { _id: 55ec4c79f30f550939227dfb,
    name: 'me',
    __v: 0,
    things:
     [ { _id: 1, name: 'one', __v: 0 },
       { _id: 2, name: 'two', __v: 0 },
       { _id: 3, name: 'three', __v: 0 } ] } ]
```

So take a good look at your data and your calls. The `.populate()` call needs to match the "path" and then also provide a "match" to query the documents that are to be populated.

Answer (score 1):

Use elemMatch:

```
var title = 'Harry Potter';
Users.find({books: {$elemMatch: {name: title}})
.exec(processResults);
```

Comment: That is not going to be of any use where "books" is an array of `ObjectId` to a referenced "Books" collection. Which is what the usage of `.populate()` here implies. Not an embedded array of documents, but just the `ObjectId` values of those documents.